# Kill -9 doesn't kill process in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

This process is marked as `<defunct>` and `kill -9` doesn't kill it. What can I do? Why can't this process be killed?

Comment: You cannot kill it because it is already dead.  That's why it's called a zombie.  ("defunct" is much less descriptive)

Comment: How did you find out it was marked as `defunct`?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of a process is called a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). Kill command has no effect on zombie processes. Technically, they are dead, and you see them just because they still have an entry in the process table.

To remove zombies from a system, the `SIGCHLD` signal can be sent to the parent manually, using the kill command. If the parent process still refuses to reap the zombie, the next step would be to remove the parent process. When a process loses its parent, init becomes its new parent. Init periodically executes the wait system call to reap any zombies with init as parent.

Answer (score 2):

Defunct means, that it's a zombie process - it's not really working, it just awaits it's parent process to call `wait` to receive it's return value.

`wait` function can be used to read the number of a signal, that killed the zombie process, so it's in fact the correct behavior.

To get rid of zombies you can:
- kill the parent process (maybe console, where you typed in your command)
- call `wait` in parent process
- ignore SIGCHLD in the parent process, if you never call `wait`